# coupled differential equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I want to solve second order differential equation connected with a first-order differential equation

```
**D[theta[x], {x, 2}] + (2*Z + P)*D[theta[x], x] -Exp[-2*Z*x]*(A*theta[x] + B^2 + C)theta[x]  == 0**,
```

with boundary conditions **theta[0]==1 and theta'[1]==0** and parameters `**Z=0.2; A=10;B=0.5; C=0.5; P=0.2;**`
and the second equation is

```
**M1==A*theta*Log[1 + T1*theta[x]] - 1/(theta[x] + T1) (2*Z + P)*D[theta[x], x] -Exp[-2*Z*x]*(A*theta[x] + B^2 + C)theta[x])**
```

I want to solve this equation in such a way to get the value of `theta` from the 1st equation and use this value in the second equation. and plot `M1` against `T1`.
i am new in Mathematica please help me.

Comment: What about parameter x in your second equation? Perhaps you want to plot M1[x,T1]?

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parameters (I changed `C` to `CC` because `C` is protected)

```
Z = 0.2; A = 10; B = 0.5; CC = 0.5; P = 0.2;
```

solution of the ode

```
\[Theta] =NDSolveValue[{D[theta[x], {x, 2}] + (2*Z + P)*D[theta[x], x] -Exp[-2*Z*x]*(A*theta[x] + B^2 + CC ) theta[x] == 0,theta[0] == 1 , theta'[1] == 0}, theta, {x, 0, 1}]
(* \[Theta][x] might be used like a build in function of Mathemtica*)
```

evaluate the second equation

```
M1 = A*\[Theta][x]*Log[1 + T1*\[Theta][x]] - 1/(\[Theta][x] + T1) (2*Z + P)*D[\[Theta][x], x] -Exp[-2*Z*x]*(A*\[Theta][x] + B^2 + CC) \[Theta][x] ; 
(*M1 depends on x and T1*)
```

plotit

```
Plot3D[ M1 , {x, 0, 1}, {T1, 0, 5}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "T1", "M1"}]
```

That's it, hope it helps!

[image]

Comment: ! thanks for your cooperation and giving time from your precious time. are any 2D plot is possible

Comment: What kind of 2D-plots? Something like M1[T1; parameter x] or M1[x; parameter T1] ?

Comment: M1[T1; parameter x]

Comment: Try `Plot[Table[M1, {x, 0, 1, .2}] // Evaluate, {T1, 0, 5}, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Range[0, 1, .2], LegendLabel -> "x" ]]`